# Benefits of using std::stop_source and std::stop_token instead of std::atomic<bool> for deferred cancellation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

When I run several std::threads in parallell and need to cancel other threads in a deferred manner if one thread fails I use a `std::atomic<bool>` flag:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void threadFunction(unsigned int id, std::atomic<bool>& terminated) {
    srand(id);
    while (!terminated) {
        int r = rand() % 100;
        if (r == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Thread " << id << ": an error occured.\n";
            terminated = true; // without this line we have to wait for other thread to finish
            return;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> terminated = false;
    std::thread t1(&threadFunction, 1, std::ref(terminated));
    std::thread t2(&threadFunction, 2, std::ref(terminated));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cerr << "Both threads finished.\n";
    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
}
```

However now I am reading about `std::stop_source`and `std::stop_token`.
I find that I can achieve the same as above by passing both a `std::stop_source`by reference and `std::stop_token` by value to the thread function?
How would that be superior?

I understand that when using `std::jthread` the `std::stop_token` is very convenient if I want to stop threads from outside the threads.
I could then call `std::jthread::request_stop()` from the main program.

However in the case where I want to stop threads from a thread is it still better?

I managed to achieve the same thing as in my code using `std::stop_source`:

```
 void threadFunction(std::stop_token stoken, unsigned int id, std::stop_source source) {
    srand(id);
    while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
        int r = rand() % 100;
        if (r == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Thread " << id << ": an error occured.\n";
            source.request_stop(); // without this line we have to wait for other thread to finish
            return;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::stop_source source;
    std::stop_token stoken = source.get_token();
    std::thread t1(&threadFunction, stoken, 1, source);
    std::thread t2(&threadFunction, stoken, 2, source);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cerr << "Both threads finished.\n";
    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
}
```

Using `std::jthread` would have resulted in more compact code:

```
std::jthread t1(&threadFunction, 1, source);
std::jthread t2(&threadFunction, 2, source);
```

But that did not seem to work.

Comment: Have you read [some documentation about them](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread#Thread_cancellation) or [thread cancellation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-thread-cancellation) in general?

Comment: The C# version of those classes behave basically the same and have some additional [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Comment: "*How would that be superior?*" You mean, besides the fact that it's self-documenting (ie: you don't have to ask what that `atomic<bool>` is for) and you don't have to write the code for it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I would still have to write code to pass std::stop_source by reference to the threadFunction? I would also have to write code to pass std::stop_token to the threadFunction? If so I now have to write the code to pass two arguments to the threadFunction instead of one.

Comment: @Andy: Passing a parameter is just *passing a parameter*; it's a trivial exercise. It's not the same thing as building the infrastructure for a thing, making sure that race conditions don't happen, and other such aspects. Also, you get the `stop_token` for free by providing the `jthread` function with a `stop_source` and a thread function that takes a `stop_token` as its first parameter. Also, why would you pass the source by reference?

Comment: @NicoBolas: `std::jthread` did not seem to work. I am guessing that the two implicitly genererated `std::stop_token` s are not connected to the source. I agree that using standard building blocks convey intent better than my homemade approach. You mention race conditions. Could that happen in my original code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It didn't work because `std::jthread` has a special feature where, if the first parameter of a thread-function is a `std::stop_token`, it fills that token in by an *internal* `stop_source` object.

What you ought to do is *only* pass a `stop_source` (by value, not by reference), and extract the token from it within your thread function.

As for why this is better than a reference to an atomic, there are a myriad of reasons. The first being that `stop_source` is a lot *safer* than a bare reference to an object whose lifetime is not under the local control of the thread function. The second being that you don't have to do `std::ref` gymnastics to pass parameters. This can be a source of bugs since you might accidentally forget to do that in some place.

The standard `stop_token` mechanism has features beyond just requesting and responding to a stop. Since the response to a stop happens at an arbitrary time after issuing it, it may be necessary to execute some code when the stop is actually requested rather than when it is responded to. The `stop_callback` mechanism allows you to register a callback with a `stop_token`. This callback will be called in the thread of the `stop_source::request_stop` call (unless you register the callback *after* the stop was requested, in which case it's called right when you register it). This can be useful in limited cases, and it's not simple code to write yourself. Especially when all you have is an `atomic<bool>`.

And then there's simple readability. Passing a `stop_source` tells you exactly what is going on without having to even see the name of a parameter. Passing an `atomic<bool>` tells you very little from just the typename; you have to look at the parameter name or its usage in the function to know that it is for halting the thread.

Comment: W.r.t. ```What you ought to do is only pass a stop_source (by value, not by reference```, is stop_token a wrapper around a handle to shared state that makes copying relatively cheap? Or are there other reasons to prefer copy by value vs. using references in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Apart from being more expressive and communicating intentions better, `stop_token` and friends achieve something really important for `jthread`. To understand it you have to consider its destructor which looks something like this:

```
~jthread() 
{
    if(joinable()) 
    {
        // Not only user code, but the destructor as well
        // will let your callback know it's time to go.
        request_stop(); 
        
        join();
    }
}
```

by encapsulating a `stop_source`, `jthread` facilitates what is called **cooperative cancellation**. As you've also noted, you never have to pass the `stop_token` to a `jthread`, just provide a callback that accepts the token as its first parameter. What happens next is that the class can detect that your callback accepts a stop token and pass a token to its internal stop source when calling it.

What does this mean for cooperative cancellation? Safer termination of course! Since `jthread` will always attempt to `join` on destruction, it now has the means to prevent endless loops and deadlocks where two or more threads wait for each other to finish. By using `stop_token` your code can make sure that it can safely join when it's *time to go*.

> However in the case where I want to stop threads from a thread is it still better?

Now regarding the feature you are requesting, that's what C# calls "linked cancellation". Yes, there are requests and [discussions](https://github.com/josuttis/jthread/issues/16) to add a parameter in the `jthread` constructor so that it can refer to an external stop source, but that's not yet available (and has many implications). Doing something similar purely with stop tokens would require a `stop_callback` to tie all cancellations together, but still it could be suboptimal (as shown in the link). The bottom line is that `jthread` needs `stop_token`, but in some cases **you** may not need jthread, especially if the following solution does not appeal to you:

```
stop_source ssource;
std::stop_callback cb {ssource.get_token(), [&] { 
   t1.request_stop();
   t2.request_stop(); 
}};

ssource.request_stop(); // This stops boths threads.
```

The good news is that if you don't fall into the suboptimal pattern described in the link (i.e. you don't need an asynchronous termination), then this functionality is easy to abstract into a utility, something like:

```
auto linked_cancellations = [](auto&... jthreads) {
  stop_source s;
  return std::make_pair(s, std::stop_callback{
    s.get_token(), [&]{ (jthreads.request_stop(), ...); }}); 
};
```

which you'd use as

```
auto [stop_source, cb] = linked_cancellations(t1, t2); 
// or as many thread objects as you want to link ^^^

stop_source.request_stop(); // Stops all the threads that you linked.
```

Now if you want to control the linked threads from within the thread, I'd use the initial pattern (`std::atomic<bool>`), since having a callback with both a stop token and a stop source is somewhat confusing.

Comment: This doesn't work if different threads need to key off of the *same* stop request. Which is what the OP asked for. You can't *give* `jthread` a `stop_source`; it always uses its internal one if you pass a function that takes a `stop_token` as the first parameter.

Comment: @NicolBolas I started by mentioning the advantage/need for stop taken. But it's fair to refer to linked cancellation as you say so added an explanation, links and a solution.Regarding internal state, passing stuff from the class etc, I already mentioned all this in my answer, hopefully it's clear enough:"As you've also noted, you never have to pass the stop_token to a jthread, just provide a callback that accepts the token as its first parameter. What happens next is that the class can detect that your callback accepts a stop token and pass a token to its internal stop source when calling it."

Comment: With linked cancellation, presumably a standalone function that takes in a parameter pack comprising of jthreads and invokes ```jthreads.request_stop()``` as done is sufficient? IOW what might the advantages be in terms of extra level of indirection via a ```stop_token```? From a dynamic memory allocation perspective is one cheaper than the other?

Comment: This answer turned out quite helpful and informative. I initially spent a long time figuring out what the many ambiguous wordings in "by encapsulating [...] calling it" refer to. I never figured it out, so maybe it could be improved. Still +1 for the rest of the background.